# Why did my code refer to Class B and not Class C?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Here is my code.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def x(self):
        print("A.x")
    def y(self):
        print("A.y")
    def z(self):
        print("A.z")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        self.a = 2
        self.b = 3
    def y(self):
        print("B.y")
    def z(self):
        print("B.z")

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 4
        self.c = 5
    def y(self):
        print("C.y")
    def z(self):
        print("C.z")

class D(C, B):
    def __init__(self):
        C.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
        self.d = 6
    def z(self):
        print("D.z")

obj = D()

print(obj.a)
```

Why does `print(obj.a)` return `2` and not `4`? I thought Python scans inputs from left to right. So with that logic it should refer to the superclass `C` and find that `self.a = 4` and not refer to the superclass `B` where `self.a = 2`

Comment: Because you're manually initializing, so your code runs in the order you specified: you first manually init C, then you manually init B, so first `self.a = 4` runs, and then `self.a = 2` runs.

Comment: Learn to use `super` correctly, instead of making hard-coded references to other classes' `__init__` methods.

Comment: This problem is also exactly what python's __a mangling is supposed to solve.  It embeds the class name in the actual variable name so that they don't step on each other.

Comment: Python isn't like Java or C++, where an object can have two fields with the same name defined in different classes. Your object only has one `a` field.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah, after reading over my explanation, I think that really is the *most important* insight here.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `obj.a` is found directly in the instance namespace, so the [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) is not really involved here.

```
>>> print(obj.__dict__)
{'a': 2, 'c': 5, 'b': 3, 'd': 6}
```

If you're asking why the instance namespace contains `a=2` and not `a=4`, it's because it was set to 4 initially and then overwritten:

```
C.__init__(self)  # sets self.__dict__["a"] = 4
B.__init__(self)  # sets self.__dict__["a"] = 2
```

Comment: With the addendum that there's nothing special happening in their code, and they almost certainly wanted `def __init__(self): super().__init__()` for that `D` class.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does `print(obj.a)` return `2` and not `4`?

Because the object `obj` can only have one attribute named `a`, and its value was most recently set to `2`.

> I thought Python scans inputs from left to right.

To **determine the class' method resolution order**, yes. However, the MRO is *only* relevant when either implicitly looking for attributes that are missing in the current class, or explicitly passing along the chain via `super`.

> So with that logic it should refer to the superclass `C`

No; when `obj.a` is looked up at the end, it doesn't look in **any classes at all** for the attribute, because **the object** contains the attribute. It doesn't look in C, B or A. It looks in `obj`, **finds** the attribute, and stops looking. (It does first look *at* `D`, in case it defines some magic that would override the normal process.)

The base classes **do not** create separate namespaces for attributes. Rather, they *are* separate *objects*, whose attributes can be found by the attribute lookup process (and, when they are, those attributes might be automatically converted via the descriptor protocol: e.g. attributes that are functions within the class, will normally become methods when looked up from the instance).

But when e.g. `self.a = 2` happens, `self` means the same object inside that code that `obj` means outside. Assigning an attribute doesn't do any lookup - there's nothing to look up; there's already a perfectly suitable place to attach the attribute. So it just gets attached there. Where it will subsequently be found.

Because the parent classes were initialized explicitly, the order is clear: `D.__init__` calls `C.__init__` which sets `self.a = 4`; then that returns and `D.__init__` also calls `B.__init__`; that calls `A.__init__`, which sets `self.a = 1`; then `B.__init__` directly sets `self.a = 2`; then all the calls return (after setting other attributes). In each case, `self` is naming the **same object**, so it sets the **same attribute** in the **same namespace** (i.e. the attributes of that object, treated as a namespace).

> and not refer to the superclass `B` where `self.a = 2`

Again, they are not separate namespaces (and unlike some other languages, not separate "parts" of the object), so `B` isn't a "place where" `self.a` can have a different value from the one it has "in" `C`. There's only one `self` object, with one `__dict__`, and one `a` (equivalently, `__dict__['a']`).

Comment: This is not exactly correct. D has to be checked for data descriptors, which have precedence over the instance dict.

Comment: Hmm, true. It would also look in D for `__getattribute__`. I'll fix that.

Comment: @wim just to make sure, it wouldn't follow the MRO looking for data descriptors, right? Otherwise I think it's fixed now.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The implementation of `object.__getattribute__` implies this lookup for data descriptors first.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part. I'm trying to condense the possibiilties for `__getattribute__` and data-descriptor magic to streamline the explanation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel And yes it follows MRO to find data descriptors

Comment: Oh, jeez. Well, good luck summarizing that in an accurate but still not distracting way. Edits are welcome.

Comment: It first looks MRO to find the attribute, then if it finds, it checks to see if it's a data-descriptor or not. If it is, it calls the `__get__`. if not, time to check instance attribute, if it finds in `__dict__` it returns it, if not, it checks to see if it's a non-data descriptor, if it is, it calls `__get__` if not if checks to see maybe it's a normal class attribute, if not it raises `AttributeError`. Then `__getattr__` comes into play :D

Comment: It is not easy to summarize. I dodged the issue by saying where "a" was _found_, rather than saying where it was looked for ... ;)

Comment: We really would benefit from a canonical that lays out the whole process with maximal accuracy while still being comprehensible.